# Как обратиться к 6 вложенному div?

Tags: html, css

Как обратиться к 6 вложенному div?

Вот как получилось у меня, есть ли лаконичный способ?

```
"& >div": {
       "& >div": {
            "& >div": {
                "& >div": {
                    "& >div": {
                        "& >div": {
                            color: red
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: и ни одного класса или id ? мрак какой.

Comment: автор же не указал для чего оно ему, может там какой-то парсер который динамически отдает сборку с каждый раз разными классами или id что генерируються из какой-то соли... мне доводилось с таким работать, когда нельзя цепляться за привычные элементы отлеживания. Но соглашусь, эт мрак

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз метки только на html|CSS то предположу что именно в этих языках нужна выборка. Можна так

```css
div{
  color:#00f;
}

div > div > div > div > div > div{
 color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Сундук
    <div>Заяц
      <div>Утка
        <div>Игла
          <div>Смерть Кощея</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нууу, может попробовать по:

- Индексу
- Свойство/Аттрибуту
- Классу
- Использовать селекторы [JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)/[jQuery](https://metanit.com/web/jquery/2.1.php)
- Обратиться к элементу внутри 6-го, а потом через [селектор](https://basicweb.ru/jquery/jquery_method_parent.php) обратиться к "родителю", т.е., к 6-му div'н